# Add a new role to existing azure cloud service using management portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-deployment

I am trying to add a new worker role to an existing azure cloud service. The existing cloud service already have a web role deployed which runs in 2 instances.

The new worker role need to run on single (1) instance.

The old ServiceConfiguration file looked like this >>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="WindowsAzure3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
<Role name="WebMVCApplication1">
<Instances count="2" />
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

the new ServiceConfiguration file looks like this >>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="WindowsAzure3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
<Role name="WebMVCApplication1">
<Instances count="2" />
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
<Role name="NewWorkerRole">
<Instances count="1" />
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

However when I upload the new ServiceConfiguration file along with the new worker role package. I get this error >> Role "WebMVCApplication1" was not found in the currently deployed service. The long running operation tracking ID was: 21xxxxxxxc42xxxxxxxxxxbda5e.

I am following this guide http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-manage/#updaterole .

I have checked both text boxes as per the document.

What I am missing here ?
Any advice will greatly help.

Many Thanks

Comment: In the link ( http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-manage/#updaterole), take a look at 1st screenshot. Please make sure both checkboxes are checked when you update the deployment.

Comment: Yes already tried that. No luck.